# Value that is dragged & dropped into Password & Confirm Password field appears as plain text

Tags: jquery, passwords, placeholder

I'm using placeholder in registration page. In that password and confirm password field is there.If we drag and drop some value into the password field, the password field is not encrypting and it's displaying the value.

[image]

In regForm,

```
->add('password','password',array('property_path'=>false,'attr'=>array('placeholder'=>'Password'))) 
->add('confirmPassword','password',array('property_path'=>false,'attr'=>array('placeholder'=>'Confirm password')))




In twigtemplate,

{{ form_widget(form.password) }}

{{ form_widget(form.confirmPassword) }} 





$(function() {
    // Invoke the plugin
    $('input, textarea').placeholder();
    var html;
    if (html) {
    $('<p class="note">' + html + '</p>').insertAfter('form');
    }
   });
```

Comment: Post your HTML and JavaScript. It's hard to debug code that you can't see.

Comment: Check if input type="password" as what @dineshkmar said

Comment: It's twig template file and yeah I have mentioned the password in the type of the password field in registration form

Answer (score 1):

check you defined input field  type as "password"

```
<input type="password">
```

Comment: yeah I have mentioned that.I'm using symfony2 and twig template.Anyway thanks for your help.